# ImportError: cannot import name 'GazeTracking' from 'gaze_tracking' (unknown location) ; give solution for this error

Tags: python-3.x

from gaze_tracking import GazeTracking
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: cannot import name 'GazeTracking' from 'gaze_tracking' (unknown location)

getting like this error while importing the gaze_tracking module

I also gone through the pip install gaze_tracking and upgrading the package and every thing but my problem not solved till now
please help me with a perfect solution